# Auto Login feature Missing from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, security

I joined the university and they gave me a email account and password.
I added that to the Mail Application from Windows.
I already remove the account from there but i still cant activate the autologin option.
How can i remove this security from my computer?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "autologin", are you talking about automatically logging into your Windows account or automatically logging into your email account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it fixed.
The Mail application added a new Security Policies so i had to reset it.
 Control Panel > User Accounts > User Accounts > On the left there was a Button to reset it, just had to press it, give Admin permission and the option of auto-login was there again.